# Given a local field is the maximal unramifield extension always finite?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

I was just wondering given a local field complete with non-archimedean valuation, is the maximal unramified extension always finite or could it be infinite? Any comments are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a finite extension of $\Bbb Q_p$ the maximal unramified extension
is infinite. It is generated by adjoining the $n$-th roots of unity
for all $n$ coprime to $p$. The Galois group is the cyclic profinite
group $\hat{\Bbb Z}$, and is naturally isomorphic to the Galois
group of the algebraic closure of $\Bbb F_p$. This is in all textbooks
on local fields, for instance Serre's.

Comment: One more tiny thing: For an equicharacteristic local field, namely $K/\mathbb F_p((t))$ finite, this is also true.

Comment: It's even easier in the equicharacteristic case: the maximal unramified extension is got by adjoining the algebraic closure of $\Bbb F_p$. @Ravi